# How do I make these LED's fade in and out at once?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, fade

so I am working on a project where I need to make the LED’s fade in and out one by one and then make them all fade in and out together at the same time. Then all LED’s should be OFF before the next pattern is determined. I've already made them fade in and out individually, but can't seem to figure out how to make all 6 LED's do it at once.

```
void setup(){
  //initialize the led pins 4-11
  for (int thisPin=8; thisPin<14; thisPin++){
    pinMode(thisPin, OUTPUT);
  }//end for
}//end setup

void loop(){
  //Fade leds up
  for (int thisPin=8; thisPin<14; thisPin++){
    for (int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue < 256; fadeValue++){
      analogWrite(thisPin,fadeValue);
      delay(2);
    }//end for
    //Fade leds down
    for (int fadeValue = 255; fadeValue >=0; fadeValue--){
      analogWrite(thisPin,fadeValue);
      delay(2);
    }//end for 
    delay(1000);
  }//end for
}//end loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to switch the loops around a bit.

Consider breaking the `for` loops out into their own functions, and your main loop will become easier to read and more maintainable.

```
void loop(){
  //Fade leds up
  for (int thisPin=8; thisPin<14; thisPin++){
    for (int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue < 256; fadeValue++){
      analogWrite(thisPin,fadeValue);
      delay(2);
    }//end for
    //Fade leds down
    for (int fadeValue = 255; fadeValue >=0; fadeValue--){
      analogWrite(thisPin,fadeValue);
      delay(2);
    }//end for 
    delay(1000);
  }//end for

  // Fade in all LEDs
  for (int fadeValue = 0; fadeValue < 256; fadeValue++) {
    for (int thisPin = 8; thisPin < 14; thisPin++) {
      analogWrite(thisPin, fadeValue);
    }
    delay(2);
  }

  // Fade out all LEDs
  for (int fadeValue = 255; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue--) {
    for (int thisPin = 8; thisPin < 14; thisPin++) {
      analogWrite(thisPin, fadeValue);
    }
    delay(2);
  }
  delay(1000);

}//end loop
```